# mysql SUM query not give expected result

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, payment_method and product_language . product_language table has Total_Room column which contains total number of rooms available and payment_method table has Room_Booked column which contains rooms booked .

I want sum of Room_Booked from payment_method when we get product_language data . If room_booked is null then sum=0 .

This is the query i try, but it gives only one record and sum=0 even if Room_Booked is not 0 .

Thanks for your help.

```
SELECT Coalesce(Sum(payment_method.`room_booked`), 0), 
       `product_language`.*, 
       `payment_language`.* AS sum 
FROM   (`product_language` 
        LEFT JOIN payment_method 
               ON ( payment_method.`product_id` = product_language.`id` ))
```

Comment: As it stands, this query will fail to run - amongst other things, it refers to `payment_language.*` on the third line, even though there is no such table/alias. Please can you include the actual query and the table structures?

Comment: if **ANY** record's room_booked is null, you'll just end up getting 0. sum(null) is null, which you coalesce to 0. you should be doing `sum(coalesce(..., 0))` instead.

Comment: I agree with Mark. I mean, don't worry bro, no one's going to steal your super-generic code that has very little context to it.

Comment: @MarcB dont he need group by as he is summing ?

Comment: oh! thats not a problem ... problem is that query is little messy so i took a small part of it ... i jus need a little clue ...

Comment: the problem is that it not give row from product_language when it not found Room_Booked data in payment_method .

Comment: @ashreva: mysql's forgiving for that, and will try to do the best it can. mssql and others would barf.

Comment: Am I reading this wrong, or does the first line (`Coalesce(Sum(...), 0)`) have no name, and the last line select multiple columns (`payment_language.*`) and try to call them all "sum". I'm surprised the latter isn't a syntax error, but I guess this is MySQL :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT `product_language`.*, `payment_language`.* , sum(coalesce(payment_method.`room_booked`), 0) as sum, 
FROM   (`product_language` 
        LEFT JOIN payment_method 
               ON ( payment_method.`product_id` = product_language.`id` )) 
group by `product_language`.*, `payment_language`.*;
```

I believe the order of your select statement is going to throw off your results. So I put the non-aggregate columns in front of your aggregate. This is a good place to start...

I also switch the coalesce into the sum, so that it's not doing coalesce on sum and does coalesce on room_booked value if null.

I added a group by statement so that you sum up on the individual entities of the rows returned.

Comments, may want to be more specific than selecting everything from Product Language, this will help weed out any unnecessary columns that it's grouping on

Comment: It's best to give at least some comment on *what* you've changed rather than just pasting a (presumably) fixed version of the example from the question.